# How to output colorful strings to telnet on Windows 7 from node over TCP?

Tags: node.js, tcp, telnet

guys. I am reading the classic Smashing Node.js: JavaScript Everywhere 2nd Edition. And I am trying to practice the code in the book about Chapter 6 TCP on Windows 7.

My code is:

```
// Dependency
var net = require('net');

// counter
var count = 0;

// create server
var server = net.createServer(function (conn) {
    console.log('\033[90m new connection!\033[39m');
    //write to the stream
    conn.write(
        '> welcome to \033[96m node-chat \033[39m!'+'\r\n> ' + count + ' other people are connected at this time.'+'\r\n> please write your name and press enter: '
    );
    // counter increment
    count++;
});

// listen

server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('\033[96m server listening on *:3000\033[39m');
});
```

After I finished the code, I ran the code via `node index.js`.
Then using `telnet localhost 3000` to connect the server.
The color of output on telnet is still black and white without any other color.

How can I see colorful output in telnet on Windows?

Comment: It's not telnet that interprets the color but the terminal. If you run telnet from cmd.com then cmd.com won't interpret the colors. If you run telnet from a vt100 emulator then it will work. Note that Hyperterminal (if you're still using Win XP) and PuTTY are great vt100 emulators. You don't even need telnet, just run Hyperterminal or PuTTY and connect using raw socket or telnet protocol.

Comment: @slebetman I don't understand that if that is terminal who interprets the color, then why `server listening on *:3000` is colored while `welcome to node-chat!` is not? I ran both index.js and telnet from cmd.exe on Windows 7. Is cmd.exe one of `cmd.com` you mentioned? BTW, what is the difference between raw socket and telnet protocol?

Comment: Hmm. As far as I know cmd.exe is not supposed to support vt100 escape sequence except for ONE specific version in Windows 10 where they enabled it but then Microsoft disabled it again by saying it was a mistake (https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/15617610--re-enable-enable-virtual-terminal-processing-by). Not sure how your code managed to work. Maybe node.js supports it but not telnet

Comment: As for telnet vs regular sockets, telnet is not a normal socket. It has a protocol which uses 0xff as the escape byte: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet. Only in 99% of text applications it looks like it behaves as a simple socket connection. But it's not (for example, the telnet protocol does not allow you to send `\r` you MUST either send `\r\n` or `\r\0` otherwise it's invalid telnet data)